# Unity Animation Curve to change value over time

Tags: unity, curves

I am trying to learn how to use AnimationCurve to change a float value over time.

However i am not really sure how to do it

Say i have the following class:

```
    public class SpiritAway : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<SkinnedMeshRenderer> MeshList;
    public List<Material> DissolveList;
    public float percentage = 0.0f;
    public bool IsDissolveing;
    public AnimationCurve Curve;

    private void Start()
    {
        percentage = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < MeshList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MeshList[i].materials.Length; j++)
            {
                if (MeshList[i].materials[j].shader.name == "Dissolve")
                {
                    DissolveList.Add(MeshList[i].materials[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (IsDissolveing)
        {
            if (percentage < 1)
            {
                    percentage += 0.01f;
                    for (int i = 0; i < DissolveList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DissolveList[i].SetFloat("_alphaClipDissolve", percentage);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i wish to incrase the percentage value with the percentage of the animation curve to get a more smooth and controlled transition of the value.

Could anyone explain how this is possible?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you've tried to use your curve so far, eg. [Curve.Evaluate(percentage)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html) — am I missing part of this question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you can replace this with:

```
public float speed = 1f/30f;
public Renderer[] renderers;
public AnimationCurve curve;

struct MaterialSlot {
    public readonly Renderer renderer;
    public readonly int index;

    public MaterialSlot(Renderer renderer, int index) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.index = index;
    }
}

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Define a material property block for modifying alpha
    // without copying materials (lighter on allocations/garbage).
    var properties = new MaterialPropertyBlock();

    // Cache an ID for our parameter, to avoid lots of string lookups.
    int id = Shader.PropertyToIndex("_alphaClipDissolve");

    float perecentage = 0f;

    // Read our alpha value from this position on the curve
    // and apply it to our property block.
    properties.SetFloat(id, curve.Evaluate(percentage));

    // Find all materials that need this alpha adjusted, and cache them.
    var slots = new List<MaterialSlot>();
    foreach(var renderer in renderers) {

        // Look at the renderer's materials without copying them.
        var materials = renderer.sharedMaterials;

        for(int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++) {
            if(materials[i].shader.name == "Dissolve") {
                // Initialize the alpha value for this material.
                renderer.SetPropertyBlock(properties, i);

                // Cache a reference to its slot so we can iterate it later.
                var slot = new MaterialSlot(renderer, i);
                slots.Add(slot);
            }
        }
    }

    // Keep updating the alpha on subsequent frames until we're done.
    while(percentage < 1f) {
        // Wait a frame, then resume.
        yield return null;

        // Advance the animation at a fixed rate over time.
        percentage += Time.deltaTime * speed;

        // Read our alpha value from this position on the curve
        // and apply it to our property block.
        properties.SetFloat(id, curve.Evaluate(percentage));

        // Apply this modified property block to every "Dissolve" material slot.
        foreach(var slot in slots) {
            slot.renderer.SetPropertyBlock(properties, slot.index);
        }
    }

    // percent >= 1f, we're done! End this coroutine.
}
```